# TFS Build Server doesn't pick up environment variables?

Tags: tfs, wix, environment-variables, tfsbuild, heat

I've been trying to use heat to generate .wxs for a WiX install project with pre-build event command line.

Everything works fine locally but despite installing WiX on the build machine, configuring environment variables, restarting the build machine etc nothing seems to recognise variables when I run a build on TFS.

For example:

```
"$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" dir $(SolutionDir)MyProject\$(OutDir) -cg MyClient -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -dr CLIENTFOLDER -var var.ClientSourceDir -out "$(ProjectDir)Client.wxs"
```

outputs

`"bin\heat.exe" dir CORRECT_PATH -cg MyClient -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -dr CLIENTFOLDER -var var.ClientSourceDir -out "CORRECT_PATH"" exited with code 3`

If I do `echo $(WIX)` it just outputs `echo`, whereas running it locally it outputs the WiX directory which seems to suggest it picks up no environment variables.

If I log on to the build machine and use the command line on it these variables are fine.

Comment: Which build are you using? VNext or XAML ?

Comment: If you log on the build machine and use MSBuild command line to build your project, are you able to get correct result?

Comment: How do you configure the environment variables? Can you provide the steps? It seems that the variable hasn't been recognized by build service account.